# Any short good introduction for mathematical proofs with minimal prerequisites?

Tags: reference-request, self-learning, book-recommendation, learning

My objective at this point is **not** to learn all and advanced mathematical proof concepts/techniques. At this point my objective is to get **basic** understanding of what is mathematical proof and learn only **basic** concepts/techniques behind them. Also, I need it to have as minimal prerequisites as possible. Best variant will be some article or tutorial or a small part of a big book. Can you please provide such material?

Comment: Although it focuses on a specific topic which may not be of interest, I'm a huge fan of how Sipser's [*Introduction to the theory of computation*]() presents proofs: the important proofs are preceded by an exposition of the idea, which helps both explain the proof itself *and* clarify the distinction between "sketch" and "(sufficiently) rigorous argument."

Comment: Prerequisites for a basic understanding of proofs is the basic vocabulary of the theory. Usually there are short lecture notes which have the important definitions and properties (they are not many usually), but they depend also on the area of your interest. Proofs are not independent of mathematical language. So I could recommend you a short lecture notes, say, on abstract algebra, to learn about algebra proofs. For example, you learn the words "groups, subgroups, cosets, partition", and then read the proof of Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: Take the textbooks you already own and learn how to prove the theorems whose results you understand. For example, prove that the square root of two is irrational or that the slopes of two non-vertical, non-horizontal perpendicular lines are negative reciprocals of each other. Learn how to prove the Pythagorean theorem. There is no book that will give any of this to you any more than there is a book that will teach you to play the guitar. You have to practice.

Answer (score 2):

You may enjoy [The Proof is in the Pudding](https://carmamaths.org/resources/jon/Preprints/Books/MbyE/Second-Ed/Material/krantz-proof.pdf), by Steven G. Krantz.

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommend Ted Sundstrom's [Mathematical Reasoning Writing and Proof](https://scholarworks.gvsu.edu/books/24/) as it is (a) freely available, and (b) more oriented towards active learning.

As an alternative that might be a bit less pedagogically oriented, but nonetheless still interesting, you can check out Clive Newstead's [An Infinite Descent Into Pure Mathematics](https://infinitedescent.xyz). I haven't spent a lot of time with this book, but I have used it for an inspiration for some exercises so it doesn't hurt to check out.